# Google Sheets Filter Assistance

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I seem to be having some problems with my filter arguments.
I'm a novice (at best) and I'm trying to learn about Excel via a home project.

Said project can be located here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mY13e-75dBYfKgkjV8dFFFEvxC838nGNxPrUdusc0PA/edit?usp=sharing
This link will enable comments.

Currently I'm struggling in Cell D13. 
I currently have 
=IF(FILTER('Dishwasher Data'!B:H,'Dishwasher Data'!H:H <=A11)
This will search by noise level.
I'm trying to create a similar search for the Min/Max decor panel sizes. This will require a <="max" and >="min" in the filter.

I have tried to replicate this using the formula used in the above cells with no luck.
`=IF($A$11>0,FILTER('Dishwasher Data'!B:H,'Dishwasher Data'!H:H <=A11), IF(Filter('Dishwasher Data'!B:H,'Dishwasher Data'!$E:$E <=A14, 'Dishwasher Data'!$F:$F >=A14)))`

Any help would be much appreciated!

If you have any questions, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=FILTER('Dishwasher Data'!B:H,'Dishwasher Data'!E:E>=A11,'Dishwasher Data'!F:F<=A11)
```

Something like this should work